# Get id of last inserted item in objectdatasource using DataSet

Tags: asp.net, insert, dataset, objectdatasource

I've done a lot of searching on this her on SO but I can't seem to find anyone who has done this. I'm sure it's a common problem but I can't figure out the right keywords to search for the solution so I'm sorry if this is a duplicate.

I have a dataset where I've used the Generate Insert, Update, and Delete statements as well as the Refresh the Data Table options so that I can retrieve the last inserted ID when I'm using an ObjectDatasource.

however, when I'm handling the ObjectDataSource-Inserted method, I'm getting a 1 as a return value, which I assume is the affected rows. I don't want that, I want the ID so that I can use it in my code.

I looked at the generated code for the insert method and it is doing a SELECT after inserting, but it returns the whole row not the ID, so how can I get at this row to retrieve the value?

Comment: actually there is a ReturnValue which is returning -1... the item is inserted but I always get a 1 for the ReturnValue no matter what!

Comment: Are you calling a stored procedure during the insert, or just a plane ordinary insert?

Comment: i'm using the standard sql generated methods that are created by the dataset when I define the initial select command.

Answer (score 0):

Something I've done in the past is to use static methods for CRUD operations.

```
<ObjectDataSource runat="server" ID="_odsThingy"
        TypeName="Northwind.ThingyFactory" SelectMethod="Select" InsertMethod="Insert">
    <SelectParameters>
        <SessionParameter Name="id" SessionField="thingyId" />
    </SelectParameters>
</ObjectDataSource>
```

and the C# code:

```
class ThingyFactory {
    public static DataSet Select(int id, /* other criteria for selecting? */) {
        // ...
    }

    public static int Insert(/* values required for insert */) {
        // do insert & return the ID
    }
}
```

I haven't tried compiling this code, so I apologize if I made some errors. This particular pattern has gotten me out of a few predicaments because of the gained control. Please read [this article](http://www.manuelabadia.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,c72852ae-1fdd-4934-a715-f565ceaf21cc.aspx) for more details on how this works.